# Jade: get variable in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I am trying to achieve the following:

My Jade page uses a `for`-loop to generate a list of items. Each item in this list has some information, displayed via Jade-variables, and a delete-button. This delete button should open a Bootstrap Modal (a pop-up window). I want the Modal to contain some of the information about the corresponding item in the list.

Here is my Jade file:

```
//Modal
.modal.fade#delPubModal(tabindex='-1', role='dialog')
        .modal-dialog
            .modal-content
                .modal-header
                    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal')
                        span(aria-hidden='true')
                        span.sr-only
                            | Close
                    h4#delPubLabel.modal-title
                            | Delete //#{pub.title} should go here
                .modal-body
                    p#modalPubTitle
                            | Are you sure you want to delete //#{pub.title} should go here
                    p
                            | This can not be undone
                    form#delPubForm.form(method='post', action='deletepublication')
                .modal-footer
                    button#modalDelPub.btn.btn-danger(type='submit', form='delPubForm')
                            | Delete
                    button.btn.btn-succes(type='button', data-dismiss='modal')
                            | Close

//List of items
ul.media-list
    - var len = pubObject.length
    - for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        //Each pub has a title
        //The title should be passed on to the corresponding Modal
        - var pub = pubObject[i]
            .panel.panel-default
                .panel-body
                    li.media
                        .media-body
                            h4.media-heading#pubTitle
                                | #{pub.title}
                            button#delPub.btn.btn-danger(data-toggle='modal', data-target='#delPubModal')
                                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash
                                |   Delete
```

How can I achieve this? I have been trying using JavaScript, but so far no success.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#delPub').on('click', function() {
        var title = $(this).closest('h4').text();
        $('#delPubLabel').text(title);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you checked, are you getting the data from backend?`onclick` of the button, invoke a javascript function and in that you can pass the data as arguments. Show us your javascript code and let's see where you are facing problem.

Comment: @NarendraSoni I have added my JavaScript code

Comment: why you don't use jade syntax to loop over an array, just write `each pub in pubObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#delPub').on('click', function() {
        var title = $('#delPub').parent().find('h4').text();
        $('#delPubLabel').append(document.createTextNode(title));
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Can you please share how did you invoke this javascript piece of code?